# SIGSEGV on SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer()

Tags: segmentation-fault, sdl-2

This code snip comes from a larger application. It compiles without any warnings but when ran it gets a segmentation fault on the SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer() call. I'm on Fedora 24 with GCC 6.1.1 and SDL2 2.0.4

```
#include <SDL.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const int window_width = 480;
    const int window_height = 360;

    SDL_Window** main_window = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer** main_renderer = NULL;

    /* initialize SDL2 */
    int ec;
    if ((ec = SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)) < 0) {
        printf("Error: couldn't initialize SDL2. EC %d\n", ec);
        printf("SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }

    /* create main window */
    if (!SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(window_width, window_height, 0,
                                      main_window, main_renderer)) {

        printf("Error: couldn't create main window\n");
        printf("SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it should. Change types to singe level of indirection (`SDL_Window *main_window = NULL;`, ...) and take address of that pointer in a call (`&main_window`, ...).

Comment: Well that fixes it. I thought SDL_Window** would work because the arg is defined at SDL_WIndow**

Comment: It isn't something I could explain in one line, but basically function takes address of a pointer to window and saves resulting window at that address. You've given NULL, so it tried to write new window pointer (window it created) at address NULL, which is invalid write.

Comment: This should be an answer.